# Facebook messenger bot from BotFramework

Tags: facebook, botframework

I am currently trying to add a bot (that works fine on other channels, written with C#) to Facebook Messenger using Microsoft BotFramework. Instructions were absolutely clear until the moment:

"Now that your app is created you need to enable it for Messaging."

Does it means that my bot should pass "App Review for Messenger" (and requires policy, screencast and so on)? If so, is there any way to test the bot without review?

I tried to perform other steps from instruction (and also looked here: http://masnun.com/2016/05/22/building-a-facebook-messenger-bot-with-python.html, where is nothing said about the review too), filling Facebook Page Id, App Id, Secret, Access Token, but Facebook Messenger channel displays an Error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

This is my first attempt to entertain with Facebook, so I will be grateful for any information what's wrong and how it can be fixed.

Comment: No it does not need to pass review, there is a section in the settings to enable messaging. If you are getting that error then there is something wrong with your bot.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, but I have nearly every other channel enabled and working properly - so I don't think it's an issue with the bot itself.  I've gone over the Facebook integration configuration about 5 times and haven't found any discrepancies (including the setting to enable messaging).  Any chance you have an update on your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it means that my bot should pass "App Review for Messenger"

No. In the beginning, you can test your bot on facebook messenger without permission but only `admin,developers,testers` in your app can chat with bot.

> Error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

If you bot work well with [Bot Framework Emulator](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/tools/bot-framework-emulator/), then mostly case is your request content is missing `Title`, you can use Emulator to check all your request. I have sample problem when follow instruction from Microsoft

```js
{
  "type": "message",
  ...
  "attachments": [
    {
      "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
      "content": {
        "title": "", //Check this
        "text": "lorem",
        "buttons": [
          {
            "type": "imBack",
            "title": "",//Check this
            "value": "lorem"
          }
...
}
```

Hopefully it can help you.